# Hibernate. Not null constraint for a few identical lists

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two simple entities (getters/setters are omitted):

```
@Entity
public class Paper {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Writer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Paper> book1 = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany
    private List<Paper> book2 = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Hibernate creates an intermediate table writer_paper with 3 columns (writer_id, book1_id, book2_id). But I can't add any papers to books because it violates a not null constraint for a second book. Can I somehow discard this constraint or circumvent it? Thank you.
**Upd**
I'm trying to add a paper to a first book like this:

```
Session session = sfbean.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

Writer writer = new Writer();
Paper paper = new Paper();
session.saveOrUpdate(writer);
session.saveOrUpdate(paper);

writer.getBook1().add(paper);
session.saveOrUpdate(writer);

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

A part of error stacktrace:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Mistake: null value in column "book2_id" violates NOT NULL constraint
  Details: Wrong string contains (670, null, 671).

Comment: Perhaps it is my fault but.. I don't understand the purpose of the two book lists for a writer.. does the writer have only 2 books? And it's not clear to me the operation that triggers the error. You should write the operations/commands you perform with the entities that trigger the error and copy the useful parts of the error. Your use case is not clear from your description. Please improve with more details.

Comment: @FabianoTarlao, this is a pure example to demonstrate an error so it doesn't matter how many books does writer have (a real code snapshot should be too verbose). I updated a post with info you requested

Comment: Quite strange, OT: I was expecting a different table mapping. Perhaps reference JPA (..and usually I define manually most of the table mappings) performs differently or I don't remind well. I think you have added now all the infos that are needed in order for other "Hibernate" guys to reply to your question. Just for curiosity, let's try adding writer.getBook2().add(paper); after writer.getBook1().add(paper); ... and see if the error is disappears. Post the case here.. and It may be useful for other ones to track the problem. Regards

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added writer.getBook2().add(paper) but it fails with the same mistake. Hibernate tries to add paper for each book separately (like (670, null, 671) and then (670, 671, null))

Comment: This is another useful proof, let's wait for other ones more competent than me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem by creating a separate link table for each list. It might be done with @JoinTable(name = "link_table_1") annotation for each list.